# How can I solve this problem in composer?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, command

I am beginner of using laravel 6, so this the error message that I faced,

> 1) SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'forge.settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `settings` where
>   `auto_load_disabled` is null)
>
> 2）SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'forge.settings' doesn't exist

even I have tried the command `php artisan migrate:fresh` but it exists the same error, the command include 
`php artisan serve, php artisan migrate`, are also not work for me..

Below are the code,

In my .env file:

```
 APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

The command `php artisan migrate:key` is not work, the error message is same to the above 1) and 2)...
and I have also try to copy another app key that can run on the server but still not work.
The database I have already create on phpmyadmin named '`forge`' using `xampp` server.

> my database.php

```
 'mysql' => [
                'driver' => 'mysql',
                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => true,
                'modes' => [
                    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
                ],
                'engine' => 'InnoDB',
            ]
```

Can anyone help me? Please..

Comment: try to run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Please share your settings table migration file

Comment: Have to cleared cache using php artisan cache:clear? Another possibility is that if you are running php artisan serve and changed env file after that you need to cancel that serve instance and restart php artisan serve.

Comment: Have you already forge database?

Comment: @HamedYarandi Yes, I have

Comment: @SumanB It is not work, the error still the same...

Comment: @J.Aaron Please make a section in your question and past your migrations file